Macbook Air Webcam not detected!
My Macbook Air 2022 M2's Webcam/Inbuilt-Camera is not being detected. Photo booth is just black with a grayed-out shutter button. This was not a problem that came out of the box, my camera worked initially but a few months ago I remember that I could have (may have misremembered this) slightly remember turning some setting off and my camera would turn off. However I only slightly remember that and it could be totally false. I need some possible solutions as I probably misremembered "turning off" the camera. If it helps my Macbook is managed by Jamf MDM and I'm not an admin.
When looking at system report under hardware and then under camera it reads "No video capture devices were found."!
I use macOS Ventura 13.5.

You write "my macbook is managed by Jamf MDM", is this a work computer? If that's the case, have you contacted IT support?
